# SQL ROWNUM how to return rows between a specific range

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rownum

How can I return a specific range of `ROWNUM` values?

I'm trying the following:

```
select * from maps006 where rownum >49 and rownum <101
```

This returns only rows matching the `<` operator.

Comment: See [**How ROWNUM works in a pagination query?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321483/how-rownum-works-in-pagination-query/30321788#30321788)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
 SELECT * from
 (
 select m.*, rownum r
 from maps006 m
 )
 where r > 49 and r < 101
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, is there a way to remove the r column after?

Comment: My quick fix is to change the first line to:
`SELECT col1,col2,col3 from`

where col1, col2 etc would be the names of all columns except r

Comment: this doesn't work on oracle if you don't give ROWNUM an alias

Comment: How to select all rows without rownum in result's set?

Comment: I get inconsistent results in Oracle using this pattern.  The double nested query below fixes the problem.

Comment: Oracle evaluates ROWNUM for the ">" and "<" comparisons like a Union, it seems. So I would not recommend using the Where clause this way with rownum.

Comment: @Vladimir, Remove * in the outer select and make the column select as you required. (Using the query in the accepted)

Answer (score 34):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  q.*, rownum rn
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    maps006
                ORDER BY
                        id
                ) q
        )
WHERE   rn BETWEEN 50 AND 100
```

Note the double nested view. `ROWNUM` is evaluated before `ORDER BY`, so it is required for correct numbering.

If you omit `ORDER BY` clause, you won't get consistent order.

Comment: I get "ORA-00904: "RN": invalid identifier" when I try something similar.

Comment: @RobinGreen: please make another question and post the "something similar" there.

Comment: I am still not getting why double nesting is required. I am trying with some data and it is giving me consistent records.`select * from (SELECT tab.*, rownum r FROM table1 tab order by cft.confrm_fraud_id) tab1 WHERE tab1.r BETWEEN 10 AND 20`

Comment: @pramod: that's because your query reads records in order of `confrm_fraud_id`, most probably using an index on it. You can't rely on this behavior. Compare these two queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4730c5/5 (incorrect) and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4730c5/7 (correct). Note that in the incorrect query  the `ROWNUM` even come in the wrong order.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. I was trying to use `ROWNUM BETWEEN 11 AND 20` for pagination on a result set with 12 rows, but was getting `0` records for any range that started `>1`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hi All , why don't we use joins instead of suqueries ? It should be more efficient...

Comment: @Kandy: we use both joins and subqueries, this is even more efficient.

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old question, however, it is useful to mention the **new features** in the **latest version**.

From **Oracle 12c** onwards, you could use the new **Top-n Row limiting feature**. No need to write a subquery, no dependency on ROWNUM.

For example, the below query would return the employees between 4th highest till 7th highest salaries in ascending order:

```
SQL> SELECT empno, sal
  2  FROM   emp
  3  ORDER BY sal
  4  OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;

     EMPNO        SAL
---------- ----------
      7654       1250
      7934       1300
      7844       1500
      7499       1600

SQL>
```

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a solution for this and found this great
[article explaining the solution](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)
Relevant excerpt

> My all-time-favorite use of ROWNUM is pagination. In this case, I use
>   ROWNUM to get rows N through M of a result set. The general form is as
>   follows:

```
select * enter code here
  from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
  a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( your_query_goes_here, 
      with order by ) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 
      :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH ) 
where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;
```

Now with a real example (gets rows 148, 149 and 150):

```
select *
    from
  (select a.*, rownum rnum
     from
  (select id, data
     from t
   order by id, rowid) a
   where rownum <= 150
  )
   where rnum >= 148;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum, * FROM maps006) AS DerivedTable
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 49 AND 101
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do using CTE with clause.

```
WITH maps AS (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS rownum,* 
from maps006 )

SELECT rownum, * FROM maps  WHERE rownum >49 and rownum <101
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from emp 
where rownum <= &upperlimit 
minus 
select * 
from emp 
where rownum <= &lower limit ;
```