# Returning rows between two row numbers (Between Range)

Tags: sql, sql-server

UsersTbl Structure:

```
id | uname
 __  ____
1  | name0
2  | name1
4  | name2
1  | name3
8  | name4
5  | name5
6  | name6
```

which kind of query that i'm looking for:

query that selects every row between row number 2 to row number 5 (without using the id column)

example:

```
//start = 2
//end = 5
select * from users where rownum >= start and where rownum <= end
```

results should be:

name2,name3,name4,name5

syntax? (mssql ,note:i'm using classic asp (Not really matters))

Comment: i couldn't use google before, now i found it...:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552769/sql-rownum-how-to-return-rows-between-a-specific-range

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to generate a row number based on the order you have shown. You can then use that in the WHERE clause.

For example:

```
SELECT
    id,
    uname,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY uname) AS rownum
FROM UsersTbl 
WHERE   
(rownum >= 2) AND 
(rownum <= 6)
ORDER BY uname
```

Answer (score 1):

This query works in SQL Serevr 2008 r2

```
with summary 

as(

select ROW_NUMBER () over (Order by uName) as rn,UNAME

from [USE])

select uname

from summary S

WHERE S.rn >2 AND S.rn <= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,uname,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY uname) AS Rownumber
FROM UsersTbl 
WHERE   
(rownumber >= 2) AND (rownumber <= 6)
```

try this i think it will work