# cx_Oracle: fetchall() stops working with big SELECT statements

Tags: python, oracle, odbc, cx-oracle, fetchall

I'm trying to read data from an oracle db.
I have to read on python the results of a simple select that returns a million of rows.

I use the `fetchall()` function, changing the arraysize property of the cursor.

```
select_qry = db_functions.read_sql_file('src/data/scripts/03_perimetro_select.sql')
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, sid)
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pwd, dsn_tns)


start = time.time()

cur = con.cursor()
cur.arraysize = 1000
cur.execute('select * from bigtable where rownum < 10000')
res = cur.fetchall()
# print res  # uncomment to display the query results
elapsed = (time.time() - start)
print(elapsed, " seconds")
cur.close()
con.close()
```

If I remove the where condition `where rownum < 10000` the python environment freezes and the `fetchall()` function never ends.

After some trials I found a limit for this precise select, it works till 50k lines, but it fails if I select 60k lines.

What is causing this problem? Do I have to find another way to fetch this amount of data or the problem is the ODBC connection? How can I test it?

Comment: can you use the sql developer tool(s) to execute the query and see if there are issues?

Comment: Also what's the point of the `arraysize` change?

Comment: With sql developer tool there are no issue. But on sql developer you only have the preview of 50 rows. If I try to export the results as csv it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider running in batches using Oracle's `ROWNUM`. To combine back into single object append to a growing list. Below  assumes total row count for table is 1 mill. Adjust as needed:

```
table_row_count = 1000000
batch_size = 10000

# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql = """SELECT t.* FROM
            (SELECT *, ROWNUM AS row_num 
             FROM 
                (SELECT * FROM bigtable ORDER BY primary_id) sub_t
            ) AS t
         WHERE t.row_num BETWEEN :LOWER_BOUND AND :UPPER_BOUND;"""

data = []
for lower_bound in range(0, table_row_count, batch_size):
    # BIND PARAMS WITH BOUND LIMITS
    cursor.execute(sql, {'LOWER_BOUND': lower_bound, 
                         'UPPER_BOUND': lower_bound + batch_size - 1})

    for row in cur.fetchall():
       data.append(row)
```

Comment: without an `ORDER BY unique_key_col` and a nested view, the `ROWNUM` can't be consistent and not of any worth. Should be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4552803/7998591) for it to work or better like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30322134/7998591) (Oracle12c and above)

Comment: Interesting...thanks @KaushikNayak. I'm not an Oracle expert.

Comment: I want to accept this answer but you need first to edit it with the suggestion of @KaushikNayak.

Comment: Whoops! I thought I did but forgot the nested subquery requirement.

Comment: getting error: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @PardeepBeniwal, please ask a new question as likely it differs from this post.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running out of memory on the computer running cx_Oracle.  Don't use `fetchall()` because this will require cx_Oracle to hold all result in memory.  Use something like this to fetch batches of records:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select employee_id from employees")
res = cursor.fetchmany(numRows=3)
print(res)
res = cursor.fetchmany(numRows=3)
print(res)
```

Stick the `fetchmany()` calls in a loop, process each batch of rows in your app before fetching the next set of rows, and exit the loop when there is no more data.

What ever solution you use, tune [`cursor.arraysize`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html?highlight=arraysize#Cursor.arraysize) to get best performance.

The already given suggestion to repeat the query and select subsets of rows is also worth considering.  If you are using Oracle DB 12 there is a newer (easier) syntax like `SELECT * FROM mytab ORDER BY id OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY`.

PS cx_Oracle does not use ODBC.

Comment: I create a loop with your suggestion but it freeze after 12500 extracted rows, no matter the arraysize. Could be some limitation on the connection or on the db user?

Comment: Are you freeing the memory at the end of each loop iteration before the next iteration?

Comment: I tried the same script on a machine with less memory space and it works.
The problem should be on the network or on the oracle client. First is a windows server with oracle12 (2014), the other is a windows 10 with oracle instantclient_18_3

Comment: The problem was in some network security rule that didn't drop the connection but was limiting the bandwidth after a certain amount of bits.
I discover it with a spool function with SQLPLUS

Comment: @paolof89, how did you track that' Can you please share further details or even the script? Thank you.