# Fetching data in Jupyter Notebook is taking too long

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cx-oracle, fetchall

I want to fetch all rows from a table, using the following code:

```
table_row_count = 1000000
batch_size = 10000

sql = """SELECT t.*
FROM (
    SELECT ROWNUM AS row_num,
           sub_t.*
    FROM (
        SELECT name_employer
        FROM my_table
        WHERE section = 'OTHER'
    ) sub_t
) t
WHERE t.row_num BETWEEN :LOWER_BOUND AND :UPPER_BOUND"""

data = []
for lower_bound in range(0, table_row_count, batch_size):
    cursor.execute(sql, {'LOWER_BOUND': lower_bound, 
                         'UPPER_BOUND': lower_bound + batch_size - 1})

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
       data.append(row)
```

The original source of the code: [cx_Oracle: fetchall() stops working with big SELECT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653947/cx-oracle-fetchall-stops-working-with-big-select-statements)

However, it is taking forever. My data has 5 mil. of rows. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Do you need to have all of the rows in memory? If so, why are you doing it in batches? If not, you can process some of the rows (or a single row at a time) and use a simple(r) query.

Answer (score 1):

For big result sets, increase `arraysize`.  Try something like `cursor.arraysize = 10000` and then tune the size to suit your data and performance requirements.

Refer to the [Tuning cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance) manual.

You may also want to look at the best practices in https://github.com/cjbj/cx-oracle-notebooks

Also see the [latest cx_Oracle release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) - it's time to upgrade to python-oracledb.