# Spring JPA Query to get Sub-List of provided IDs not in Table

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way using a Spring JPA Repository Query to get a sub-list of the IDs that were not present in our table given a list of IDs?

Something like this:

```
@Query(value = "Some query returning a sublist of orderIds not in TABLE")
List<String> orderIdsNotInTable(@Param("orderIds") List<String> orderIds);
```

I found a link [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141129/find-ids-from-a-list-that-dont-exist-in-a-table) but I cant think of how to make that a JPA Query.

**EDIT:** The goal here is to save on running memory so if there are thousands of ids and many calls happening at once I would like it to be handled without creating a second copy of all the ids potentially.

Comment: have you considered using a native query or you want to stay DB-agnostic?

Comment: @vladtkachuk I think DB agnostice because this query will have to work on to different DB systems

Comment: How many elements do you have in your list of IDs?

Comment: @Olivier could be a frw thousand but potentially multiple api calls happening at once each with that many

Comment: Will most IDs be missing from the table?

Comment: @Olivier likely only a few is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

As from what your questions asks, my solution would be:

1. retrieve the list of IDs present in your database:

```
   @Query("select t.id from Table t")
    List<String> findAllIds();
```

2. Loop through the list of IDs you have and look up if the list of IDs from the database table does not contain your id.

```
 List<String> idsNotContained= orderIds.stream()
    .filter(!findAllIds()::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I would ideally like everything to be done in thenquery as to save memory within the api.

Comment: You need to understand one thing that the db will return either only a list of values present in the database or an empty list based on your argument.  For comparison pruposes, you shall implement a logic (subroutine) at query level that would return the values whose ID has not matched your ID column in the database.

Comment: so you dont think what they did in the link i provided is possible with jpa?

Comment: In the link you have provided they are adding the missing value somehow on the database `with v (id) as (
 values (4),(5),(6)
)`, he wants the value 5 that doesn't exists in the database, and if you don't provide somehow the value you need in the database it is not feasible

Comment: @NickPavini How will a list of String IDs would consume memory in your API. Does your list contains 1 M records? In this case bring subsections of the list from the select until you reach end of list and then do your comparison for each sub sections.

Comment: Perform a query first to get the count of total records in your select. Then divide by the number of records you want your list to fetch per each query. Then you query by first rownum and last rownum until count value. Do your comparison as above. This will be possible to achieve by Native JPA query as well as save memory. See [ROWNUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552769/sql-rownum-how-to-return-rows-between-a-specific-range)

Comment: @Pawan.Java `ROWNUM` is specific to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Pawan.Java solution, I would look for the ids and then apply the filtering.

```
List<String> findByIdIn(List<String> ids);
```

The list which is returned will contain the ids which exist, it is then just a matter of removing those ids from the original list.

```
original.stream().filter(i -> 
  !existingIds.contains(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If there is a large number of ids being passed in, then you might want to consider splitting them into parallel batches.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is not too big, then an easy and efficient solution is to retrieve the IDs from the list that *are* in the table:

```sql
select t.id from Table t where t.id in (id1, id2, ...)
```

Then a simple comparison between initial and returned lists will give you the IDs that are not in the table.

Comment: Your answer is good but write in Java to provide a complete one.

Answer (score -3):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.id FROM TABLE t WHERE t.id NOT IN :orderIds")
List<String> orderIdsNotInTable(@Param("orderIds") List<String> orderIds);
```

I don't know if I understood you correctly but can you try the solution above.

Comment: This query will output all the IDs that are not present in the argument passed. From my perspective, the question is looking for all the IDs that have not returned an object from the database and hence output those.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That returns rows that don't match order ids. He want's to get ids that are missing - ids that returns "no" row